# Rails/ReactJs View not updating on Browser Refresh

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, github, rubymine

Just recently, I have added Reactjs to my Rails application. However, whenever I reload the same .jsx file, but with different content (ie `<h1>Hello<h1/>` to `<h1> Hello again<h1/>`), the browser does not respond and update the view. I have tried restarting the server and reloading the page. I have also created a separate rails application, and I was able to recreate Furthermore,I have also pulled my partner's repositories to check if there were any file differences. There were none.

***However***, when I pull his repo, my browser updates the content, but it doesn't update it anymore afterward when I edit a .jsx file. It should also be noted that when I edit the content on a .jsx file, the view updates for him, but it doesn't update for me when reloading the page. Our files are the same, but only I have the problem. I have also toggled safe mode, but it didn't make a difference.

I am using Webpacker with Yarn on Jetbrains' RubyMine with Windows 10. Here is a picture of what the problem is:
[The code vs the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxFE1.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Did you try turning off the cache of your browser? You can do so in your developer console.

Comment: @adriaan Thank you for the warm welcome. I have not. Let me try that and get back to you.

Comment: @adriaan I turned off the cache for Firefox Developer Edition and it gave the same result. To make sure I did it right, I tried loading the same page on Windows Edge, something that has no history of the localhost server, and it gave the same result.

Comment: This could be a turbolinks issue. If you close the page and open it, is it updated?

Comment: @Redline no success there. I want to think it is getting the file information elsewhere instead of from the javscript/components directory, but I don't know where else it could be.

Comment: Could you link to a github repo?

Comment: @Redline, I can't provide my exact repository due to the projects underlying nature, but I was able to recreate the problem just by installing webpacker with Reactjs and updating yarn on another project. Discovering the problem here will fix the problem on my personal repo too. It should be noted in the webpacker.yml file,  check_yarn_integrity was set to false to get past yarn issues. Even when updating yarn, the problem was still present. here is the repository: [basic links] (https://github.com/ultimateweapon9/SOHelp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a great amount of trial and error, the problem was with the IDE and where it was retrieving its settings and files from. I had a backup HDD that held old information on it such as my last projects contents. This was wiped.

I also managed to find old IDE settings in my "../users/%your_name$/.Rubymine2018.1". All old RubyMine settings were removed. I also reinstalled my IDE to give it yet another clean start. As far as I can tell, this has worked.

A big thanks to everyone who helped me in the comments!

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing the same issue, and as I have tried to follow the guide provided previously I couldn't know where to start from.

And what I had to do is to run `npm run build` everytime I update my jsx in my component.